# Как нарисовать что-либо в объекте `Canvas` окна `JFrame` с применением `BufferStrategy`?

Tags: java

Как нарисовать что-либо в объекте `Canvas` окна `JFrame` с применением `BufferStrategy`?

Comment: "Прошу предъявить исходники" - а документы у вас есть, на каком основании мы вам должны что-то предъявлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примеров масса, главное лишь поискать:

```
package testframe;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Testframe extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    //FIELDS
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running;
    private Thread t1;


    public Testframe(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        frame = new JFrame();
    }


    public synchronized void start (){
        running = true;
        t1 = new Thread (this);
        t1.start(); // calls run()
    }


    //Main runnable
    public void run(){
        while (running){   
           update();
           draw();
        }
    }


    public void update(){}


    public void draw(){
       BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
       if (bs== null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
       }

       Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       g.fillOval(0, 0, 20, 20);
       g.dispose();
       bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Testframe myPanel = new Testframe();

        myPanel.frame.setResizable(false);
        myPanel.frame.setTitle("My frame");
        myPanel.frame.add(myPanel);
        myPanel.frame.pack();
        myPanel.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myPanel.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myPanel.frame.setVisible(true);

        myPanel.start();
    }
}
```

<sub>Пример с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770830/java-buffer-strategy-learning)</sub>